# Codeigniter sessions - multiple identical computers on same IP address

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm running across a scenario with a web app that's written in Codeigniter and uses the session library (it's Codeigniter pre-3.0, so it's perhaps the older session library).

The scenario is that this particular use case have multiple absolutely identical laptops (Chromebooks) on the same network (same external IP address) saving data with session data to mysql. How can I tell each session apart? They will all have identical user agent's, identical IP addresses, etc.

The background on this is that each user account is tied to a session and when data is saved, some users are overlapping sessions with other users, thus creating inaccurate data about what user saved what data.

Is there a way to make it more specific so the correct user is accurately detected?

Comment: Even if two people have the same IP and UA string the session still relies on a random ID that's generated for every user. You shouldn't have session clashes despite this.

Comment: I guess that presents a different issue then. Users were saving data, but the saved data was being assigned to other users. It only happened when everyone (10 people) were trying to do similar tasks at the same time while sitting next to each other. We've used it with 300 other users daily for 10 months without issue, but previous users all had non-identical machines... any ideas on what it could be if not overlapping sessions? Something specific to Chromebooks perhaps?

Comment: Hard to say without any hard data to go on, but it *could* be an actual session collision problem. The session manager is supposed to generate a random ID for every session. If the source of entropy for that random ID is poor (e.g. older unsupported versions of PHP or just a poorly configured box) then it's possible for two users to end up with the same session ID. This is especially possible when a server is under very heavy load where many concurrent requests occur. However, don't let CodeIgniter's nonsensical concept of tieing the session to an IP/UA confuse you. It's utterly useless.

Comment: Like many things in CI perhaps ;) - thanks for the insight. this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that this is the result of a session collision, but keep in mind that the *real* distinguishing factor behind a session is the `sessionID` and not the IP or UA string. That is to say even if two users both have the same remote IP and UA string in a request where neither of them already have a session cookie in their browser, they should still each be assigned a randomly generated (*hopefully unique*) `sessionID`, thus still distinguishing their sessions.

If you're using CI to store session in the DB there is a simple test you could do to detect whether or not a session collision has in fact occurred. In the session driver, where the session is created, check the DB table you're using for storing sessions for an existing session ID (bar matching IP/UA) against the newly generated session id by the driver and `log` the matching IDs.

At least this way you'll have some indication of whether or no it's actually happening and how frequently it's happening.

---

Some of the root causes for session collision is poor source of entropy (PHP uses `/dev/urandom` by default as of PHP 5.4, but CI may do something different); using high-collision rate hashes like md5 (try sha256 or better instead); or just having too many concurrent workers overloading the server (try lowering your php-fpm or apache prefork `max children` setting, for example).

It's important to note that PHP doesn't inherently attempt to prevent session collision in general. This is mostly because such checks at runtime would be a performance cost and the expectation is that the probability of a collision occurring is rather low with good configuration (although not impossible). [PHP has tons of settings for fine-tuning this](http://php.net/session.configuration) in its own session manager, although codeigniter does it's own thing (and I can't be bothered to read their documentation to figure out what they do wrong to be honest).

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this. I figured out a way around this by passing along the session info for the creator on data initialization event rather than detecting the session info on the data save event. It's not ideal perhaps, but it solves the issue quickly.

Comment: HI, can you clarify this please? I'm getting the same thing, it's really obscure!